# How to remove the vendor text that shows up in checkout page of woocommerce?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My website is built upon wordpress and woocommerce. I am using Dokan multivendor plugin. At the checkout page at the right side under the "Your order" section it shows first the product name then below that date and time of booking and below that the name of the vendor. I want to remove the function to show the name of the vendor in the checkout page.

My website is [www.osdoc.in](https://www.osdoc.in/) .. you can try and add a product and go to checkout page to see which one i am asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide it using css:

```
.woocommerce td.product-name dl.variation .variation-Vendor {
    display: none;
}
```